# Notched box with border

Tags: html, css

What i need: a box with notched angle, a border around it and png image inside.
What i have: a box with notched angle made with linear-gradients, a border around it and png image **over the border**.
What i've tried: change z-indexes - zero result.
Any idea?

My code: https://codepen.io/drsg/pen/eYZEXNz

```
.item {
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
   width: 340px;
   height: 380px;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, orange 30px);
   z-index: 999;
}

.item::before {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   left: 10px;
   top: 10px;
   display: block;
   width: 320px;
   height: 360px;
   background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, black 30px);
   overflow: hidden;
}

.item__image {
   position: absolute;
   bottom: -90px;
   left: -105px;
   width: 370px;
   height: 360px;
   z-index: 1;
}

.item__image img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
}

body {
   background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try with this css:

```
.item {
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 340px;
    height: 380px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, orange 30px);
  z-index: 999;
}


.item::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 320px;
    height: 360px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 30px, black 30px);
    z-index: 1;
}

.item__image {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: 320px;
    height: 360px;
    background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.item__image img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: -80px;
    left: -80px;
}

body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Jeroen Bourgois! That's work very fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Using clip path you can get the same effect.

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: orange;
    clip-path: polygon(24% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 23%);
}

.box::before { 
  display: block;
    background-color: black;
    content: 'hello';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    clip-path: polygon(24% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 23%);
}

.box img {
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: -35px;
  left: -60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://pngicon.ru/file/uploads/vinni-pukh-v-png.png" />
</div>
```